# Children class editing parents self in CustomTkinter Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, inheritance, arguments, customtkinter

I know that this problem maybe can be simple, but I'm not a profissional on python. Its is the problem:

I stated a program in Python 3.8.6 with Custom Tkinter, and I'm having a problem with inherit. The Code:

```py
from customtkinter import CTk, CTkButton, CTkFrame


class Base(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.btn_newUser = CTkButton(master=self, command=master.RemoveFrame(master.base),
                                     text="Criação de Usuário", anchor="EW") \
            .grid(row=0, column=0, padx="30", pady="10", sticky="ew")


class App(CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Crypton - Python Encryptor")
        self.geometry("840x480")
        self._set_appearance_mode("light")

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.base = Base(master=self)
        self.AddFrame(self.base)

    def RemoveFrame(self, frame):
        frame.grid_forget()

    def AddFrame(self, frame):
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = App()
    window.mainloop()
```

I need to forget and add a frame to a grid that is on the parent (App) inside the son (Base), without the parent (App), this is possible?

Obs: I tried to use the grid_forget on the son, but the Frame don't hide.

If have another solution, I'm open, I only need to show multiples screens on a same window in an alternate way.

I tried to create a def inside the parent to the son run, but says that don't have a "base" on "self.base".

Def:

```
def RemoveBaseFrame(self):
    self.base.grid_forget()
```

Pycharm Erros:

> Cannot find reference 'RemoveFrame' in 'Misc | None'
> Cannot find reference 'base' in 'Misc | None'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `command=master.RemoveFrame(master.base)` will executed the function *immediately* and `master.base` is not created yet (it is being created).

Use `lambda` instead: `command=lambda:master.RemoveFrame(master.base)`.

Comment: Thank you, this works sucessfully!

Answer (score 0):

I can't resolv the question, but this works fine to me:

```
from customtkinter import CTk, CTkButton, CTkFrame


class Frame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = "blank" #base, blank

    def ReturnOpenFrame(self):
        return self.__value

    def CloseFrames(self, master):
        if self.__value == "base":
            master.base.grid_forget()
            self.__value = "blank"
            print("close base")
        else:
            self.__value = "blank"
            print("set blank")

    def OpenFrames(self, master, frame):
        self.CloseFrames(master=master)
        if frame == "base":
            master.base.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.__value = "base"
            print("set base")
        else:
            print("else set")


class App(CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myframe = Frame()
        self.title("Crypton - Python Encryptor")
        self.geometry("840x480")
        self._set_appearance_mode("light")

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.Start()

        self.myframe.OpenFrames(self, "base")


    def Start(self):
        self.Base()

    def Base(self):

        self.base = CTkFrame(master=self)

        self.base.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.base.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.base.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.base.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.base.btn_newUser = CTkButton(master=self.base, command=lambda: self.myframe.OpenFrames(self, "blank"),
                                          text="Criação de Usuário", anchor="EW") \
            .grid(row=0, column=0, padx="30", pady="10", sticky="ew")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = App()
    window.mainloop()
```

If you are questioning how it help me, well, I needed to use a class to manage the current screen, so, on this code the "Frame" class are doing this function. I'll need to put all the new Frames on this function, but at least I will manage the current screen.

I know, because I see on a code, that have a easy form to do it with a json packet, but for know this will work fine.